# How law can help me if someone using my name join a zoom class and tell teachers bad words?

Tags: privacy, online

Nowadays during lockdown Online classes are happening in the Zoom app.
Teachers share the Zoom meeting link where we do our classes. As here anybody can join with any name and someone joins in zoom class using my name and writes bad words in chatbox about the teaching of teachers. I told that to the teacher. But in some class where I haven't attend as these are not of me, he join these classes and tell teachers bad words. By my friend, I know about this. So I want to take legal action about this. How Law can help me?

Comment: Which jurisdiction (i.e. which set of national or state laws) are you in? India?

Comment: yes, I am from india

Answer (score -2):

Under [Sec. 205 of the Indian Penal Code](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1346193/),

> Whoever falsely personates another, and in such assumed character
>   makes any admission or statement, or confesses judgment, or causes any
>   process to be issued or becomes bail or security, or does any other
>   act in any suit or criminal prosecu­tion, shall be punished with
>   imprisonment of either description for a term which may extend to
>   three years, or with fine, or with both.

The parties violated the law by making statements, pretending to be you. Prosecution is always discretionary, but the police will not do anything if nobody files a complaint.